# ussd reader in Recket Native module

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, kotlin, ussd

## I have this code that opens a window for a phone I want when it doesn't open that window and send me the result send ussd to fronend in react native

```
class UssdModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "UssdModule"
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun openUssdDialog(ussdCode: String) {
        val encodedUssdCode = Uri.encode(ussdCode)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:$encodedUssdCode"))
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        currentActivity?.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited from original answer:  It turns out they added support in Android 26 to make a USSD call.  The function is TelephonyManager.sendUssdRequest.  It does not exist on devices older than 26.  And what ussd commands are supported is not specified, I would only rely on the bare basics and not advanced menu functionality.

Still if you have any other way of getting that information use that instead.  In reality-  USSD is kind of a dead technology.  It existed in pre-data days to provide limited ability to make network calls.  In the modern day when every phone has data there's no advantage to using it over a web service.  Remember that USSD codes vary by OEM, carrier, etc-  they are not universal.  So by using any USSD code at all you are limiting your app to working on only a subset of phones most likely by a specific OEM or carrier.  Expect to have a low Play Store rating because you'll be given 1 stars by everyone without that model/carrier who downloads your app.

Comment: I do not want a connection to the API of USSD, I just want to send USSD and receive the results without the appearance of this window for the Android system, very simply that my application is in the place of the call application 

As for this technology, it is still used in many countries of the world, it is not dead.

Comment: Actually I'm going to delete the comment I just made-  it turns out they added new USSD APIs, but only in Android 26.  Which is kind of amusing since for over a decade my original answer was correct-  that it was impossible to do on Android, as Android did not support USSD.  So older devices can't do it, but newer ones can.  You also need the CALL_PHONE permission.  But really look for any other tech that can do the same thing, because there is no documentation on what USSD strings are supported if you go beyond the basics (for example does p for pause work?)